# Windows Search cannot index A:\ drive

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I have a secondary drive on my Windows 7 Ultimate laptop. On the secondary drive I have all my Documents and Media. I have pointed all my library locations to the secondary drive. I also attempted to update the Windows Search index to include the updated drive locations. However, when I rebuild the index I get the following error:

```
The content source <A:\Downloads\> cannot be accessed.

Context: Windows Application, SystemIndex Catalog

Details:
    The specified address was excluded from the index. The site path rules may have to be modified to include this address.  (HRESULT : 0x80040d07) (0x80040d07)
```

I can successfully add other folders on my system drive to the index and have them be indexed however I cannot get these directories to work. Is this a result of it being on the A:\ drive? I can't see why, but that's something Microsoft would do.

**Other items checked:**

- SYSTEM has access to the drive and all the directories I want
  searched.
- I have the "Allow files on this drive to be indexed..." and the
  "Allow files in this folder to be indexed..." options set on all the
  directories I want searched.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm thinking this is caused by the fact that historically A: has been reserved for a floppy drive (along with B:), and as documents on these drives are of a very transient nature, indexing them makes no sense.

It would not suprise me if there is some obsolete Windows95/98 code around (which, if i remember correctly, was when search indexing was first implemented, and floppies were still common) with a hardcoded exception for A: and B:

Try remapping the drive to D: or something else and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I am super worried that is the case. I am testing it now. Here goes nothing.

Comment: That was it. Cruft code is the best isn't it? I tested both A:\ and B:\ and they both exhibit the same issue. Changing the drive to D:\ fixed it.

Comment: I just want to say this saved my dad's bacon. Thank you for your comment. Must be arbitrary code nobody has bothered to change. Thumbs up, and repped.

Comment: Search indexing started in XP.  You do not remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest mapping it to a different drive letter.  Use a letter higher than the latest one being used by hardware.  If C is the highest, then map it to D.  Since A and B are usually reserved for floppy drives back in the day, that may be a factor.

Or figure out how to change the rules mentioned in the error message.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean regarding the "rules mentioned in the error message." Aren't those the Indexing rules?

Comment: Hmm, I don't remember either @prateek61.  Maybe I was referring to the site path rules but I don't know what those refer to.  I see that Jarmund basically had the same answer with more info.  I don't think there are any rules against D even though that usually got assigned to the CD drive, like I said map to the "highest" open.

Comment: I did not anticipate a follow up two years later. Thanks though! It did end up working out.